# Regular expression: everything except Latin letters

Tags: php, regex

1)How to say in regular expression: increase match counter only if there are no letters at all?

I came up with this:

`"/^[^a-zA-Z]+$/"`

and it seems to work, but I don't get why `"/^[^a-zA-Z]+/"` doesn't work while `"/[^a-zA-Z]+$/"` works?

2)What does this mean?:  `"/[a-zA-Z]+/"` I thought it means that match counter will increase only if all the elements will be in range a-z or A-Z. But testing shows I'm wrong. Also tried this `"/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+/"` but this also give 1 for "aa11".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only correct regular expression you've posted is `/^[^a-zA-Z]+$/`. All the rest are wrong.

You need the `^` and `$` to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the match to the start and end of the string respectively.

- `/^[^a-zA-Z]+/` matches `aaa111` because there's no end-of-string anchor.
- `/[^a-zA-Z]+$/` matches `111aaa` because there's no start-of-string anchor.
- `/[a-zA-Z]+/` matches `111aaa111` because there's no start- or end-of-string anchor. It matches if there's any letter anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to just use `/^[:alpha:]+$/`
you start regex with a dilimeter which can be anything so `#^[:alpha:]+$#` also works. `^` is the start of the input and `$` is the end. `+` is for a match of 1 or more. [tutorial/info](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php)